# Different results from numpy interp and Matlab interp1d - linear interpolation

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

This is my first StackOverflow question, so please be patient. I have searched for  couple of days with no luck. I'm a PhD oceanography student, and am learning Python 3 (and NumPy and XArray) by converting some substantial Matlab code to Python.

I've found a difference when linearly interpolating. The original code uses Matlab's interp1d function, and I'm using numpy's interp function. Most of the time the results are the same, but there's a slight difference where there are NaN values within the data.

Say I have a 1D array, e.g., temperature at a particular depth, measured over increasing time, and it has NaN values at certain points. The Matlab code interpolates it over a longer time series, with usually the same time increments, effectively putting the shorter timeseries within the longer (please don't tell me there are better ways of doing this, I'm just trying to deal with this issue at the moment :-) ).

The Matlab interpolation leaves the temperature values as they are; but the Numpy interpolation removes the last, pre-NaN values. 
If I use a mask to remove the NaNs, it leaves all the values, but fills in any NaN sections not at either end.

e.g. (original record)

```
[nan nan 3.0 4.0 3.5 nan nan 2.0 3.2 3.1 1.5 nan nan]
```

Matlab gives:

```
[nan .... nan nan nan 3.0 4.0 3.5 nan nan 2.0 3.2 3.1 1.5 nan nan ... nan]
```

Numpy gives either (no nan mask):

```
[nan .... nan nan nan 3.0 4.0 nan nan nan 2.0 3.2 3.1 nan nan nan ... nan]
```

or (with nan mask):

```
[nan .... nan nan nan 3.0 4.0 3.5 3.1 2.4 2.0 3.2 3.1 1.5 nan nan ... nan]
```

Are there any arguments that I should be passing to np.interp to get the same result as the Matlab function? Or is it just a difference of the language and I have to deal with it? The only arguments I'm using at the moment are

```
left=np.nan and right=np.nan.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the actual code, and not just the results?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and get it to reproduce with a subset of the data - code is simple, data is pretty hefty to put on here...

Comment: I will second the others: put some code, it is to me not clear what are you exactly doing. Also, I honestly cannot understand this: _The Matlab code interpolates it over a longer time series, with usually the same time increments, effectively putting the shorter timeseries within the longer_

Comment: The full time series is around 13 years; each mooring is around 18 months. The interpolation puts the mooring data within the full time series, so if the first mooring is 734 records long, it will make up the first 734 records of the full time series (around 10000 records) after interpolation, and so on until the whole time series is complete. Usually the time increments are the same but they may not be.
 
Again, this may not be the best or most efficient way of doing this (scientists are not always great coders), but I'm trying to duplicate it before I improve it...

Comment: @ocean_phd it looks like a similar question was posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032848/why-does-matlab-interp1-produce-different-results-than-numpy-interp/56049313#56049313. Is this the same problem you are observing?