# Why does Matlab interp1 produce different results than numpy interp?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, interpolation

**EDIT:** Code edited to produce results consistent with Matlab. See below.

I am converting Matlab scripts to Python and the linear interpolation results are different in certain cases. I wonder why and if there is any way to fix this?

Here is the code example in both Matlab and Python and the resulting output (Note that t just so happens to be equal to tin in this case):

**MATLAB:**

```
t= [ 736696., 736696.00208333, 736696.00416667, 736696.00625, 736696.00833333, 736696.01041667, 736696.0125];
tin =[ 736696., 736696.00208333, 736696.00416667, 736696.00625, 736696.00833333, 736696.01041667,  736696.0125];
xin = [   nan , 1392.,  1406. , 1418.  ,  nan , 1442. ,   nan];

interp1(tin,xin,t)

ans =

 NaN        1392        1406        1418         NaN        1442         NaN
```

**Python (numpy)**:

(scipy interpolate.interp1d produces the same result as numpy)

```
t= [ 736696., 736696.00208333, 736696.00416667, 736696.00625, 736696.00833333, 736696.01041667, 736696.0125];
tin =[ 736696., 736696.00208333, 736696.00416667, 736696.00625, 736696.00833333, 736696.01041667,  736696.0125];
xin = [   nan , 1392.,  1406. , 1418.  ,  nan , 1442. ,   nan];

x = np.interp(t,tin,xin)

array([   nan,  1392.,  1406.,    nan,    nan,    nan,    nan]) 

# Edit
# Find indices where t == tin and if the np.interp output 
# does not match the xin array, overwrite the np.interp output at those 
# indices 
same = np.where(t == tin)[0]
not_same = np.where(xin[same] != x[same])[0]
x[not_same] = xin[not_same]
```

Comment: I don't know for Python but Matlab has 9 different methods which can be used by `interp1` ... Python must have several methods too. Since you didn't explicitely specify a method in any code above, are you sure the _default_ settings are the same for both language ?

Comment: By the way, your question is very similar to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50612085/3460361), where you already had comments asking you to show some code. If you are the same person, it would be better to edit the other question by adding the info and code shown here (and when the other question is complete you can delete this one to avoid redundant questions).

Comment: It's because your y values have nans. Presumably the numpy implementation does something like `y1 + (y2-y1)*(x-x1)/(x2-x1)` and the `nan` is propagated to the result and the matlab code has a special check `if (x == x1) return y1`.

Comment: @Hoki I am aware of that question but it wasn't be who asked it. I replied to it by adding my code (because one of the commenters asked for it) but a moderator deleted it so I decided to make a new one. 

Also, both numpy and matlab default is linear interpolation.

Comment: @user545424 You are most definitely correct. I am now checking for cases where x == x1 and return y1 and I get results that are consistent with matlab.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if Matlab includes an additional equality check in it's interpolation.

Linear 1-D interpolation is generally done by finding two x values which span the input value `x` and then calculating the result as:

```
y = y1 + (y2-y1)*(x-x1)/(x2-x1)
```

If you pass in an `x` value which is *exactly* equal to one of the input x coordinates, the routine will generally calculate the correct value since `x-x1` will be zero. However, if your input array has a `nan` as `y1` or `y2` these will propagate to the result.

Based on the code you posted, my best guess would be that Matlab's interpolation function has an additional check that is something like:

```
if x == x1:
    return y1
```

and that the numpy function does not have this check.

To achieve the same effect in numpy you could do:

```
np.where(t == tin,xin,np.interp(t,tin,xin))
```